# Rigid Body Object Jumps back when keyframing "animation" off

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to get a box to float into the air, fly in a direction and then midair activate physics so that it flies off and falls to the ground without me having to animate that. I tried keyframing the "animate" toggle so that it turns off, but when I do this, the box jumps back to its starting position, instead of continuing from where the animation left off. How do I enable physics mid-animation?[image]

Comment: Can you make sure that your object is an *active* rigid body and can you add a screenshot of your rigid body settings? Also have you tried baking the animation or are you only playing it back.

Comment: Yes it is an active rigid body, no I'm just playing it back. What will baking the animation do? Would I do that before or after I keyframe the "animated" toggle? I've added a picture of my rigid body settings for the cube. Thank you!

Comment: You might have an invalid cache.  Try starting and cancelling a grab operation on the rigid body to reset the cache, then try again.  If not, save and load and check behavior; if still a problem, link the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the simulation *Start* and *End* frames under
*Scene Properties > Rigid Body World > Cache*.

[[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You have to bake your rigid body into a bunch of keyframes. This will basically turn the physics simulation into a bunch of keyframes. You can do this by pressing  <kbd>F3</kbd> and searching `Bake to Keyframes`.

Comment: To make it work properly it's not necessary to turn the bake into keyframes. If the simulation is setup correctly and baked it doesn't need to convert it into keyframes. I suspect the OP set it up incorrectly, but since he didn't react to it for more than two years now I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score -1):

At frame 0 put your object at its beginning location in the scene, press <kbd>i</kbd> > *LocRotScale*, enable the *Animated* option in the Physics panel and press <kbd>i</kbd> to keyframe it. At frame 10, move your object wherever you want, press <kbd>i</kbd> > *LocRotScale*, disable the *Animated* option in the Physics panel, press <kbd>i</kbd> to keyframe it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm doing this, but disabling "animation" under the rigid body settings causes the object to return to its starting point. Any idea why that might be happening? When I make a new simple animation, it seems to work how you have described, but when I try to keyframe the "animation" toggle on top of my existing animation for the cube, it jumps back to its starting position instead of falling from the sky.

Comment: I don't think this answer describes what the OP wants.

Comment: @clankill3r, maybe I've misunderstood the initial question, maybe explain or give your own answer?