# Gravity with rotation/ momentum

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I want some coins to fall in a "box". I enabled gravity for them and they do fall, but it looks really fake, because they just move down as they are and don't rotate while they fall.

They just fall like a brick with linear movement downwards and only the impact is realistic.

How can I get some rotation/ movement in the fall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start your render range at some positive frame (or use negative frames) and keyframe a starting motion to your objects.  The rigidbody sim will consider the object's current motion vector when it takes over the simulation.

I used this method here: https://youtu.be/f036R6d_DiQ?t=44

You can change the *Rigid Body Cache* settings under *Scene Properties* if you want to change the simulation range or bake the sim.

[image]

You'll need to keyframe the *Animated* checkbox under the object's *Rigid Body* settings in *Physics Properties* to inform the system that it will be controlled by animation up until the frame you've decided.

[image]

In this example I just used two keyframes on a Cube's *Rotation* on frame 1 and 10, and told my Rigid Body sim that I'd be controlling the sim with animation until frame 5.

[image]

Comment: Great video :D Thanks for your help!

Comment: it's weird. The maker of the video has the same video as you here..... :D :D :D

Comment: Quick follow up to this one: I can't rotate my object, that's because of the checkbox "Animated" in rigid body is disabled. Explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138924/rigid-body-object-jumps-back-when-keyframing-animation-off). The solution is to change the simulation cache start. But in your file you also have the simulation start at 1. What am I overlooking?

Comment: @jona I've set keyframes for everything in my file, if you try to rotate normally it'll be overridden by the animation system whenever the timeline changes.  Is that what you mean? (Sorry I missed this comment)